# Javascript get nested array value

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck and need som help.

I have a nested array with array keys like `[1,2,3,4,5]` and this could be from 1 to unlimited keys.

I need to get the value of the last array, hardcoded i could do this: `array[1][2][3][4][5]` but i am looking for a more dynamic way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```js
function access(arr, indexes) {
    while (indexes.length > 0) {
        arr = arr[indexes[0]];
        indexes = indexes.slice(1);
    }
    return arr;
}

const arr = [[[[[123, 234]]]], [[],[],[[],[],[],[[],[],[],[],[0,0,0,0,0,987]]]]];

console.log(access(arr, [0,0,0,0,0]));
console.log(access(arr, [0,0,0,0,1]));
console.log(access(arr, [1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function lastval (arr) {
  return (arr instanceof Array) ? lastval(arr[arr.length - 1]) : arr;
}

console.log(lastval([[[[[3,535,35], [2553, [535, 19]]]]]]));
```

Edit: I think I misunderstood the question. My answer gives the last nested value of a given array.

Comment: After I saw your answer I reread the question. For me the question is unclear now :-D

Comment: @ThomasSablik I think your answer is correct.